# Why didn't Wade stay back with Upham?

Tags: saving-private-ryan

In Saving Private Ryan, Captain Miller and his team attack a radar station in this following scene:

Their medic Wade also attacks with them and later dies. My question is why did Miller allow Wade in the attack? Wade doesn't even have any weapons.Why didn't Wade just stay back with Upham?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upham was a liability for sure because he had very little weapons training. His primary job was to translate and push pencils.

But Wade was a field medic. He has survived Omaha beach assault and was trained to treat injured patients in middle of action.

If a soldier is injured in middle of fight it's difficult to locate and move them through firefight. In such cases a field medic has to reach him and give necessary treatment. That's their priority.

This situation was no different for Wade. That's why he followed everyone else in the battle.

Comment: Couldn't Wade just stay away from the firefight and then locate the wounded after the fight? The fight was a short one, he could've treated other later.

Comment: @iamgroot: You never know how long the firefight is going to last. Injured soldiers need quick attention from somebody who know how to administer. Wade died primarily because of his wound and also because no one else knew how to patch his wounds.

Comment: @iamgroot - Yes, and no. A field medic can very well locate a wounded soldier after a firefight if his friendly force were to control the area after the firefight. There is no guarantee that this will be the case. In which case, the medic has two functions, to treat and to evacuate the wounded soldier. For them to do that, they have to be close to the wounded soldier. Fighting back through enemy occupied territory before the wounded soldier dies is not an option.